# Is there something wrong with my link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= link_to 'show', :controller=>:users, :action=>:show, :id=>u.id, :confirm=>'are you sure?' %>
<%= link_to 'reset pass.', :controller=>:users, :action=>:reset_password, :id=>u.id, :confirm=>'RESET PASSWORD, are you sure?' %>
```

The first link works fine, but the second is really strange... sometimes it works, and sometimes is doesn't and causes such an error:

> LoadError in UsersController#index
>
> Expected
>   /home/anonym/Documents/RubyOnRails/authorisation/loginout/app/controllers/users_controller.rb
>   to define UsersController

Moreover it doesn't show confirmation box. Anyway if I remove :confirm option the first error occurs anyway from time to time.

Controller:

```
#users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
...
def reset_password
    @user=User.find_by_id(params[:id])
...
```

Routes:

```
#routes.rb
match 'users/:id/reset_password', :to=>"users#reset_password"
```

It could be understandable to me if it failed everytime but is it's kind of random.

Any ideas why?

**UPDATE**

This little modification in controller seemed to fix the problem.

```
#Thread.new{UserMailer.reset_password(@user, passwd).deliver}
UserMailer.reset_password(@user, passwd).deliver
```

This also caused my sqlite database to collapse (if I clicked the link very fast a few times).

Do you know why this thread might have been such a killer?

And there still is the question why there is no confirmation box?

**UPDATE**

```
Started GET "/users/2/reset_password?confirm=RESET+PASSWORD%2C+are+you+sure%3F" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:03:57 +0100
  Processing by UsersController#reset_password as HTML
  Parameters: {"confirm"=>"RESET PASSWORD, are you sure?", "id"=>"2"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.4ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36m (0.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = 'my_email@gmail.com' AND "users"."id" != 2) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.3ms)[0m  UPDATE "users" SET "last_support_email_sent_time" = '2012-02-06 14:03:58.182567', "encrypted_password" = '5380187f533d14e2867667f8c2c9dc6671b1d930ff892a8cb4da7cdda99d01c8', "updated_at" = '2012-02-06 14:03:58.186194' WHERE "users"."id" = 2
Rendered /home/anonym/Documents/RubyOnRails/authorisation/loginout/app/views/user_mailer/reset_password.html.erb (0.2ms)

Sent mail to my_email@gmail.com (1270ms)
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2012 15:03:58 +0100

from: User service

To: my_email@gmail.com

Message-ID: <4f2fddce433d3_2c275ca2fa664560@anonym-laptop.mail>

Subject: Your new password

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: text/html;

 charset=UTF-8

Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit



Hello ,</br>

Your new password is: 469ff56728

Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users
Completed 302 Found in 1407ms


Started GET "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:03:59 +0100
  Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (1.1ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY email
Rendered shared/_add_to_user_index_row.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered shared/_add_to_user_index_row.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered shared/_add_to_user_index_row.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered shared/_add_to_user_index_row.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered shared/_add_to_user_index_row.html.erb (0.1ms)
Rendered shared/_add_to_user_index_row.html.erb (0.2ms)
Rendered /home/anonym/Documents/RubyOnRails/authorisation/loginout/app/views/users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (75.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 197ms (Views: 132.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:04:00 +0100
Served asset /jquery_ujs.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:04:00 +0100
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/loginout.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:04:00 +0100
Served asset /loginout.css - 404 Not Found (39ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/loginout.css"):


Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (2.1ms)


Started GET "/assets/jquery.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:04:00 +0100
Served asset /jquery.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/messages.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:04:00 +0100
Served asset /messages.js - 304 Not Modified (1ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:04:00 +0100
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (2ms)


Started GET "/assets/auth_engine.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:04:00 +0100
Served asset /auth_engine.css - 304 Not Modified (2ms)


Started GET "/assets/sessions.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:04:00 +0100
Served asset /sessions.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/users.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:04:00 +0100
Served asset /users.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-06 15:04:35 +0100
SQLite3::SQLException: unsupported file format:           SELECT name
          FROM sqlite_master
          WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: unsupported file format:           SELECT name
          FROM sqlite_master
          WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
):
```

After that database is broken - server restart doesn't help. This occures from time to time eventhough I no longer use Threads.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?  Is it 3.0, or something more recent?  Can you post what's contained in your development.log after a failure?

Comment: @Ryan I'm using rails 3.1.3. Development log added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Rails is not thread-safe.  If you need to perform background operations, use something like [Spawn](http://github.com/tra/spawn/tree/edge) or [DelayedJob](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job)

As for the confirmation, do you have an application.js in your **app/assets/javascript** folder, and do you have `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` in the <head> of your layout?

If the application.js file isn't being loaded, none of the Rails JS will run, which includes confirmations.

**Update:** I see the problem now.  The `link_to` method takes two types of options, first the options for routing, then the options for the HTML.  **:confirm** is one of the HTML options.

If you're going to pass routing and HTML options, you need to separate the routing options into their own hash first, like so:

```
<%= link_to 'show', { :controller=>:users, :action=>:show, :id=>u.id }, :confirm=>'are you sure?' %>

<%= link_to 'reset pass.', { :controller=>:users, :action=>:reset_password, :id=>u.id }, :confirm=>'RESET PASSWORD, are you sure?' %>
```

As the log demonstrates, your confirm is being passed as part of the path generated by the `link_to`, rather than being included in the HTML of the generated **a** element.

Comment: Yes, it is there, anyway confirmation works for a link above. Maybe it only applies to the restful stuff?